# how to set row number in sybase query

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a select statemnt which will return results say 1000 using join with some 3 to 4 tables.  My requirement is to have identity column in the resultset . Can anyone help me on this.

ex :

```
Result :
id   name 
--   ----
001   xxx
002   yyy
003   zzz

My requirment :
Rowid   id   name 
 1      --   ----
 2       001   xxx 
 3       002   yyy
 4       003   zzz
```

Like Row_number in sql , do we have anything here in sybase

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In sybase there isn't `row_number` or something like that. Maybe temporary tables with identity column will help you?

Consider below example please.

```
 select Rowid = identity(8), id, name      
 into #temtab
 from tab

 select Rowid, id, name
 from #temtab
```

Comment: what do you think of my answers for future developer ?

Comment: @Moudiz It would be harder for more complicated tables structure.

Comment: do you recomand to remove it or keep it with more explanation ?

Comment: @Moudiz In my opinion it should be removed. Your answer doesn't solve OP's problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the version of Sybase IQ I use, version Number() or ROW_NUMBER() functions exist. In my version you may use following:

```
select Number() rowid, id, name      
 from tab
```

or

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) rowid, id, name      
 from tab
```

or

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rowid, id, name      
 from tab
```

Comment: But what if you don't want to order by ROW_NUMBER()?